# why is rhumb line bearing for this question 270 as the answer?

Tags: great-circle

An aircraft leaves position "G" in lat 40 degree South and flies the following Rhumb Line tracks and distances:

```
G to H : 180 (true) 240 NM 
H to J : 270 (true) 240 NM
J to K : 000 (true) 240 NM
```

what is the rhumb line bearing from G to K ??

According to me answer should be **090** but it is given as **270** ..

can someone please give the reason for the same

Answer (score 1):

The only movement in the east-west direction is your 2nd leg, moving west. Therefore, from the starting point G to the ending point K, the bearing is west, 270 degrees. The answer 090 would describe the course from K to G to close the path.

```
K--->090--->G
^           |
|           V
J<---270<---H
```

All the legs are the same length, and the north/south aren't drawn to the same scale as the east/west, but it's just a square.  270 from H to J, so 090 from K to G.  And thus 270 from G to K.

Comment: The bearing is correct, but the legs are *not* all the same length because the surface of the Earth is curved. The distance K <-> G will be larger than the other legs since the question said we are south of the equator.